# Is there a way to compare the changes between two arrays using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compare

I don't just want a true or false if they are the same or not, but rather the number of differences between the two arrays. Is this possible using a function within numpy or do I have to figure out a mathematical expression between conditional statements?

Comment: What's the `dtype` and `shape` of these arrays?

Answer (score 1):

- If `a`, `b` are *any* np.arrays (regardless of dimensions), the simple `a == b` will return a numpy array of the same size, with boolean values. Trues = they are equal in this coordinate, and False otherwise.
- The same goes for `a != b`, with inequality instead of equality.
- Summing over this np.array, will yield the number of True entries, which is the number of entries in `a` which differ from `b`.

So to sum up, to know how many entries in `a` and `b` differ, you use: `(a != b).sum()`.

I have assumed that the entries are scalars, and that you are looking for strict equality. Other functiions exist if you are looking for entries which are "close enough" to each other (look for np.isclose).